# Finding the basis for W perp when the null space of the span of W is 0

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality

This question requires me to calculate the basis of W perpendicular. 
W = Span{$\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$,$\begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\\1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$}

If I set A = $\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\1&0\\0&1\\1&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$ and the basis for W to **x**, I know that A ∙ **x** = 0, by the definition of orthogonality.

Thus, to find **x** I am looking for the null space of A.
However, I am fairly positive that the null space of A contains only the trivial solution. Is it even possible for the basis of W perp to be {0}, or am I just making an error? If it is possible, I'm having a hard time conceptually grasping why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misformulating the problem: if you're looking for $W^\perp$, you should interpret $W$ as a subspace of the `dual` of $\mathbf R^5$, i.e. write vectors in $W$ as `row` vectors, so that 
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&1&1\\-1&0&1&0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$ 
Then solve via row reduction:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&1&1\\-1&0&1&0&1\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&1&1\\0&1&1&1&2\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-1&0&-1\\0&1&1&1&2\end{bmatrix}.$$ 
So an orthogonal vect $\;{}^{\mathrm t\!}\begin{bmatrix}x,y,z,t,u\end{bmatrix}$ satisfies 
$$\begin{cases}
x=z+u\\y=-z-t-2u
\end{cases}$$
This shows $W^\perp$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf R^3$, and a basis of  $W^\perp$ is, for instance the image of the canonical basis of $\mathbf R^3$ under this isomorphism:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\quad\begin{bmatrix}0\\-1\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},\quad\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}.$$